# How to calculate accuracy in my dataset using Restricted Boltzman Machine (RBM) in R?

Tags: r, rbm

I want to calculate the accuracy of my dataset using Restricted
Boltzman Machine (RBM) in R. I have installed rbm packages from
Github; Timo Matzen in order to use the package in my coding with my
own dataset. I have success in training and testing my dataset.
However, I am not able to calculate the rbm accuracy when I run the
PredictRBM function in R. I don't know what is the error to obtain the
accuracy. My number of rows and columns for both train and test
dataset is already the same.

I have created for CSV files which is trainX.csv, trainY.csv,
testX.csv, testY.csv and upload it in my R coding. All of the dataset
have same number of colums and rows. Then, I have train and test all
of the dataset CSV files using RBM method in packages installed from
GitHub. The train and testing dataset is successfully run. However,
when I tried to run the PredictRBM function, there is an error which
may refer to the i and j columns in dataset. So, I could not calculate
the accuracy of dataset using RBM method.

```
#First install devtools 
install.packages("devtools")
#Load devtools 
library(devtools)
#install RBM 
install_github("TimoMatzen/RBM",force = TRUE)
#load RBM 
library(RBM)

trainX <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\DefaultUser.DESKTOP-9JB0E7L\\Desktop\\project R\\trainX.csv') 
trainY <-read.csv('C:\\Users\\Default User.DESKTOP-9JB0E7L\\Desktop\\projectR\\trainY.csv') 
testX <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\DefaultUser.DESKTOP-9JB0E7L\\Desktop\\project R\\testX.csv') 
testY <-read.csv('C:\\Users\\Default User.DESKTOP-9JB0E7L\\Desktop\\projectR\\testY.csv')

attrainX <- as.matrix(trainX) 
attrainY <- as.matrix(trainY) 
atestX <-as.matrix(testX) 
atestY <- as.matrix(testY)

#First get the train data from trainX 
train <- attrainX
#Then fit the model 
modelRBM <- RBM(x = train, n.iter = 1000, n.hidden = 100, size.minibatch = 10)
#Get the test data from testX 
test <- atestX
#First get the train labels of trainY 
TrainY <- attrainY
#This time we add the labels as the y argument 
modelClassRBM <- RBM(x = train, y = TrainY , n.iter = 1000, n.hidden = 100, size.minibatch = 10)
#First get the test labels of testY 
TestY <- atestY
#Give our ClassRBM model as input 
PredictRBM(test = test, labels = TestY, model = modelClassRBM)
```

I expect to obtain the accuracy of dataset using RBM method using
PredictRBM function : `PredictRBM(test = test, labels = TestY, model = modelClassRBM)` However, there is an error which is :

> ```
> #Give our ClassRBM model as input  
> PredictRBM(test = test, labels = TestY, model = modelClassRBM)
> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , 12, value =0): subscript out of bounds '''
> ```

Do you know why these error appear? Thank you in advance.

This is my output if it does not have error
[image: This is my output if it does not have error]

Comment: How does your data differ from the working examples in the documentation? Can you please properly format your code chunk (remove `>` where not necessary, comment non-executable code, remove `*` where not appropriate...)?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. My post has been edited. I would like to ask for your help on how to get the dataset accuracy using RBM method. I have an error if I run the PredictRBM function in R. Do you know why does the error appear ?